# How to use a hook to override an update_post_meta call in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, customization, hooks

A plugin I'm using contains the following code:

```
    $download = array(
        'post_title'   => $title,
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_author'  => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_type'    => 'dlm_download'
    );

    $download_id = wp_insert_post( $download );

    if ( $download_id ) {

        // Meta
        update_post_meta( $download_id, '_featured', 'no' );
        update_post_meta( $download_id, '_members_only', 'no' );
```

I want to create my own plugin to set the _members_only value to yes in all cases. So far the code I've got is:

```
function dlmc_members_only_default( $check, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value )
{
    // Avoid infinite recursion:
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ ); 

    // Modify the meta value;
    $meta_value = "yes";

    // Update the modified value.
    update_post_meta( $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value ); 

    // Return something else than null
    return true; 
}
add_filter( 'update_post_metadata', 'dlmc_members_only_default', 11, 5 );
```

Unfortunately this seems to put wordpress into an infinite loop, despite the line intended to stop that. Is there a better way to achieve my goal? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try [this hack](http://pastebin.com/3acVpPih) I am not sure whether that would help but I am hooking into `wp_insert_post` to set a hint for updating meta later..

Comment: @SamuelElh that seems to work! Thanks very much! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hook into the hooks provided in `update_post_meta()` function and still use this function in your callback, that would result in a loop which would probably end with the timeout..

As the per the comments:

```
add_action("wp_insert_post", function( $post_ID ) {

    if ( ! $post_data = get_post( $post_ID ) ) return;

    // try to make this run only once needed ( from the question, the content is empty and cPT is dlm_download )
    if ( "dlm_download" == $post_data->post_type && ! $post_data->post_content ) {
        update_option( "dlm_download_members_only_yes", $post_data->ID );
    }

    return;

}, 10);

add_action("init", function() {
    if ( $pid = (int) get_option( "dlm_download_members_only_yes" ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $pid, "_members_only", "yes" );
        delete_option( "dlm_download_members_only_yes" );
    } return;
});
```

`init` hook is always there (page load, AJAX, etc) so this should always work and would work on multiple entries as well..